# How can I temporarily disable a route in web.php laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I have routes in web.php that open my website login page and other pages. I want to disable the login page without going to web.php to put a comment on it. I want it to be manageable in the admin dashboard where I can put a button to disable the login that target the specific route.. Specifically the index /.

Here is the route in web.php

```
Route::namespace('Front')->group(function(){
    Route::get('/', 'IndexController@index');
   
  Route::post('/login', 'UsersController@loginUser');
      Route::group(['middleware'=>['front']],function(){
        Route::get('/logout', 'UsersController@logout');
        Route::get('/user-dashboard', 'UsersController@userDashboard');
        

   
    });
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... what have you attempted so far? what research have you done to solve your problem? what do you intend the function of "disabling" a route to be?

Answer (score 0):

There is not built in feature for this, but having some logic dependent on the environment variables will do this.

In your `UsersController.php` add logic similar to this.

```
public function loginUser()
{
    if (env('DISABLE_LOGIN')) {
        return response('', 503);
    }
}
```

Will disable the endpoint if the env is set to.

```
DISABLE_LOGIN=true
```

Skip over the check if the env is.

```
DISABLE_LOGIN=false
```

Comment: i would assume they would be using a config var not `env` since that would return `null` if cached